# When to execute database migration?

Tags: database, database-design, database-migration

New to database migration. Assuming I have:

1. A new and empty database
2. A new server with migration files that never being executed

Now, I start my server and new tables will be created because the server executed the migration operations. My questions are:

1. Should the migration operations be executed again if the server is turned off and on?
2. If there is no new migration files being added to the server, there shouldn't be any changes to the existing database, correct? From what I have tested, the database does not have anything done to it if there is no new migration files being added to the server.

Comment: I think depends on what you are using for your migration scripts?  Flyaway, manual, something else?  Without that info though if nothing is changing to any of the objects in the DB there should not be a need to migrate till there are changes.

Comment: Those scripts will be used to create tables and establish relationships between tables using foregin keys in a database without the need to create tables manually from eg PgAdmin for Postgres. Not sure what flyaway means but i will look it up.

Comment: The migration depends on the model, for the first run you must do migration, after if you make any change to the model you must do migration too

Comment: @Holzer, I don't think I can make changes to the existing migration file / model because there will be a conflict and the operation will never be executed. If I need to make new changes to the existing model, I need to write another migration script to alter the table. This response might be out of the topic but that is what I learned from my experiments. Am I correct?

Comment: The migration have two steps:the creation and the application. First you make your change and save the file. Second, you make the migration and the result will be seen in the database. Remember if you change the model and not migrate the change, it will be bad for the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial database creation scripts should be idempotent. They should be able to execute in an `if not exists create table` fashion.

If your codebase defining the application changes at all, the framework you use to autogenerate your migration files should pick up on that and generate the deltas for you.

Comment: Great point, create table only if the table doesn't exist make sense. Thank you.